# Coeff. of $x^{97}$ in $f(x) = (x-1)\cdot (x-2)\cdot (x-3)\cdot (x-4)\cdot ........(x-100)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, sums-of-squares, multinomial-coefficients

> If $f(x) = (x-1)\cdot (x-2)\cdot (x-3)\cdot (x-4)\cdot ........(x-100)\;,$ Then Coefficient of $x^{99}$ and
>
> Coefficient of $x^{98}$ and Coefficient of $x^{97}$ in $f(x).$

$\bf{My\; try::}$  We can write $f(x)$ as

$$\displaystyle f(x) = x^{100}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100}i\right)x^{99}+\left(\mathop{\sum^{100}\sum^{100}}_{i=1\ \ j=1\ i<j}i\cdot j\right)x^{98}-\left(\mathop{\sum^{100}\sum^{100}\sum^{100}}_{i=1\ j=1\ k=1\ i<j<k}i\cdot j\cdot k\right)x^{97}+..$$

So $\bf{Coefficients}$ of $$\displaystyle x^{99} = -\sum_{i=1}^{100}\left(1+2+3+......+100\right) = -\frac{100\cdot 101}{2} = -5050$$

Similarly Coeff. of $$\displaystyle x^{98} = \mathop{\sum^{100}\sum^{100}}_{i=1\ \ j=1\ i<j}i\cdot j = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100}i\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{100}i^2\right] = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{100\cdot 101}{2}\right)^2-\frac{100\cdot 101\cdot 201}{6}\right]$$

But I did not understand How can i calculate Coeff. of $\displaystyle x^{97} =-\mathop{\sum^{100}\sum^{100}\sum^{100}}_{i=1\ j=1\ k=1\ i<j<k}i\cdot j\cdot k$

Help me, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the coefficient of $x^{97}$ you can apply a method similar to the one you used to find the coefficient of $x^{98}$. You already noted that the coefficient $C$ of $x^{97}$ is
$$C:=-\mathop{\sum^{100}\sum^{100}\sum^{100}}_{i=1\ j=1\ k=1\ i<j<k}i\cdot j\cdot k=-\sum_{i=1}^{98}\sum_{j=i+1}^{99}\sum_{k=j+1}^{100}i\cdot j\cdot k.$$
We can compute $C$ from the identity
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100}i\right)^3=-2\sum_{i=1}^{100}i^3+3\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100}i^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{100}j\right)-6C.$$
Rewriting the above yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
C&=&-\frac{1}{6}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100}i\right)^3+2\sum_{i=1}^{100}i^3-3\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100}i^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{100}j\right)\right],\\
&=&-\frac{1}{6}\left[\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot100\cdot101\right)^3+2\cdot\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\cdot100^2\cdot101^2\right)-3\cdot\left(\tfrac{1}{6}\cdot100\cdot101\cdot201\right)\cdot\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot100\cdot101\right)\right]\\
&=&-20618771250,
\end{eqnarray*}
modulo miscalculations.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+product%5B%28x-k%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C100%7D%5D), $C=-20618771250$.

Comment: I found $\frac{1}{48}\left(n-2\right)\left(n-1\right)n^{2}\left(n+1\right)^{2}$ and substitution $n=100$ says that wolfram is correct. Though, the expression for $C$ looks okay to me.

Comment: @Servaes : You treat $C$ as $-C$ (note that $C$ is negative). Your answer seem correct except the very last calculation.

Comment: Is there a general method available to find the coefficient of any term like suppose,find the coefficient of $x^{81}$.@Servaes